# Slow query with Having on calculate field

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, having

I have a query that is slow... i want to display the last 12 newest members near me(near the logged user) and my dev database has 150k rows.

It took over 1 second and the explain query tells me that 30k rows are filtered
So 30k filtered for 150k rows in my developpment DB... my server online is much bigger thant this....

Here my query :

```
SELECT  profils.*,
        Users.username,
        ( SELECT  count(*)
                from  profilsphotos pp
            where  pp.iduser=Profils.iduser
        ) as nbpics,
        ATAN2(SQRT(POW(COS(RADIANS(50.78961000)) * SIN(RADIANS(Y(gm_coor) - 4.64956000)),
                        2) + POW(COS(RADIANS(X(gm_coor))) * SIN(RADIANS(50.78961000)) - SIN(RADIANS(X(gm_coor))) * COS(RADIANS(50.78961000)) * COS(RADIANS(Y(gm_coor) - 4.64956000)),
                                                2)), (SIN(RADIANS(X(gm_coor))) * SIN(RADIANS(50.78961000)) + COS(RADIANS(X(gm_coor))) * COS(RADIANS(50.78961000)) * COS(RADIANS(Y(gm_coor) - 4.64956000)))
             ) * 6372.795 AS distance
    from  Users
    inner join  Profils  ON Users.id=Profils.iduser
    where  Profils.Actif=1
      and  profils.idsexe=2
      and  profils.idlookingfor=1
      and  Profils.iduser<>1
    HAVING  distance<400
    order by  Users.id desc, distance asc
    limit  12
```

Note that i add an index on those four fields: actif,idsexe,idlookingfor and iduser

What wrong with my query ?

Thanks a lot !

Pascal

Comment: Can you paste the explain output as well as the result of this query: select count(*)
from Users
inner join Profils on Users.id=Profils.iduser 
where Profils.Actif = 1 
and profils.idsexe = 2 
and profils.idlookingfor = 1 
and Profils.iduser <> 1

Comment: Hello Mark,
Same thing.... 30k filtered....

Answer (score 0):

`Profils` needs

```
INDEX(Actif, idsexe, idlookingfor) -- in any order
```

Perhaps `distance` should be first?..

```
order by  Users.id desc, distance asc
```

What is `Y(gm_coor)`?  If is a Stored Function, we need to know more.  What table has `gm_coor`?  After that, maybe we can discuss a "bounding box" as a partial speedup.

Make another nesting of `SELECTs` and move the computation of `nbpics` to it.  Currently, the `COUNT(*)` is being performed 30K times.  After the change, it will be only 12 times.

**Reformulation**

```
SELECT  p2.*,
        u.username, 
        ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  profilsphotos pp
            where  pp.iduser = p2.iduser 
        ) as nbpics,
        x.distance
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  p1.id,    -- assuming this the PK of Profils
                  (...) AS distance
            FROM  Profils AS p1
            WHERE  p1.Actif=1
              and  p1.idsexe=2
              and  p1.idlookingfor=1
              and  p1.iduser<>1
            HAVING  distance < 400
            ORDER BY  distance
            LIMIT  12 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  profils AS p2 USING(id)
    JOIN  Users AS u  ON u.id = p2.iduser;
```

Comment: Hello Rick ! 
Same things... over 30k rows... I added actif,idsexe, idlooking for as index.... I change the order by to : order by disrance asc, users.id desc.. Still the same...

Comment: I remove all... the distance fields, the order by distance, the order by users.id, the nbpics fields. Here is my where clause with NO order by:
where Profils.Actif=1 and profils.idsexe=2 and profils.edlookingfor=1 limit 12.. and still 30k rows ??? Why ?

Comment: Perhaps you did not understand what I meant.  See my Reformulation.

Comment: Hello Rick ! Sorry for that ! I didn't understand well... so i tried what you suggest to me but it still 30k rows... but i see 12 for the nbpics... So the problem... it can be the indexes ? can i force a specific index.... note that i have a lot of different index for this table... Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @pascal22 - Hmmmm...  It might help if you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` ; there may be some clues in them.

Comment: Hello Rick ! Yes of course i can do it.... but i have a problem... i wanted to copy and paste your query (reformulation) and now i have errors.... few days ago... the query was OK but i had to change something but now i can't find what to change.... I dont know if i can add another answer an add a picture or paste my code...

But the error is at that line: ( SELECT  p1.id,    -- assuming this the PK of Profils
I remove the comments but i still have the error... here the details of this error :

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 9. I 'm Sorry, i had to change some fields name.... because in my first posts, i rename some fields name because some was in french.... it's my mistake.. sorry about it.. i will not do it again....

But the problem is that i donc have the "( LIMIT 0, 25" in my query....

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: here the error line :
SELECT p2.PkUsager,p2.FkUsager, u.NomUsager, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profilsphotos pp where pp.FkUsager = p2.FkUsager ) as nbpics, x.distance FROM ( LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: and in my query ... i don't have : "( LIMIT 0,25" ??? i really dont know wherer the error was... it works few days ago...

Comment: `... FROM ( LIMIT ...` is not valid syntax.  `... FROM ( SELECT ... LIMIT ... )` may be what you wanted?

Comment: Hello Rick, i know but the problem is i dont have LIMIT in the select query... it's the exact query you sent to me..... is it a bug from my MYSQL version ? i have the version 5.7.14. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the subquery from the SELECT clause to a temporary table, index it and join to it, instead of executing it for every record in the select clause (30K times).

So the steps are: create a temp table, index it, run the optimized query.

First, create the relevant indexes for the query:

```
ALTER TABLE
  `Profils`
ADD
  INDEX `profils_idx_actif_iduser` (`Actif`, `iduser`);

ALTER TABLE
  `Users`
ADD
  INDEX `users_idx_id_username` (`id`, `username`);

ALTER TABLE
  `profils`
ADD
  INDEX `profils_idx_idsexe_idlookingfor` (`idsexe`, `idlookingfor`);

ALTER TABLE
  `profilsphotos`
ADD
  INDEX `profilsphotos_idx_iduser` (`iduser`);
```

Now, create the temp table and index it:

```
-- Transformed subquery to a temp table to improve performance
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS SELECT
        count(*) AS nbpics,
        iduser 
    FROM
        profilsphotos pp 
    WHERE
        1 = 1 
    GROUP BY
        iduser 
    ORDER BY
        NULL;

ALTER TABLE
  `temp1`
ADD
  INDEX `temp1_idx_iduser_nbpics` (`iduser`, `nbpics`);
```

Now try to run this query instead of the original one and see if it runs faster:

```
SELECT
        optimizedSub1.*,
        temp1.nbpics 
    FROM
        (SELECT
            Users.username,
            ATAN2(SQRT(POW(COS(RADIANS(50.78961000)) * SIN(RADIANS(Y(Profils.gm_coor) - 4.64956000)),
            2) + POW(COS(RADIANS(X(Profils.gm_coor))) * SIN(RADIANS(50.78961000)) - SIN(RADIANS(X(Profils.gm_coor))) * COS(RADIANS(50.78961000)) * COS(RADIANS(Y(Profils.gm_coor) - 4.64956000)),
            2)),
            (SIN(RADIANS(X(Profils.gm_coor))) * SIN(RADIANS(50.78961000)) + COS(RADIANS(X(Profils.gm_coor))) * COS(RADIANS(50.78961000)) * COS(RADIANS(Y(Profils.gm_coor) - 4.64956000)))) * 6372.795 AS distance 
        FROM
            Users 
        INNER JOIN
            Profils 
                ON Users.id = Profils.iduser 
        WHERE
            Profils.Actif = 1 
            AND profils.idsexe = 2 
            AND profils.idlookingfor = 1 
            AND Profils.iduser <> 1 
        HAVING
            distance < 400 
        ORDER BY
            Users.id DESC,
            distance ASC LIMIT 12) AS optimizedSub1 
    LEFT JOIN
        temp1 
            ON temp1.iduser = optimizedSub1.iduser
```

Comment: Hello Tomer, thanks ! It 's the same... 30k rows.... Also... is that normal... i should always recreate the temp table ? because, if i copy and paste your last query... MySQL said that temp1 doesn't exist! Thanks for your help !

Comment: @pascal22 - the temporary table will be available only for that specific session, so it should be created and indexed every time, just like running the query. Was the execution duration improved overall?

Comment: ok i understand... thanks for your explanation. the time is the a bit slower.: the old query is 0.2619 seconds and your query is 0.1734 creating the temporary table + 0.1920 seconds for the select Query...